# Android background data of my app wrong?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a geo tracking app with the front-end done in PhoneGap and the tracking is done in a native plugin. The only part of the plugin that creates network connections is when I post the location to the server, which is less then 1 kB per post. As expected the bigger part of the traffic is done by the HTML+JavaScript front end.

BUT last week I encountered a crazy problem, where my Galaxy S4 Mini reported insane amounts of background data, something like 500 mb in a couple of hours. To investigate this is started profiling the network traffic: I tagged the part where the geo location is posted to the server and monitored the traffic with ddms/monitor. Most of the time the app was behaving as expected, a little bit of foreground traffic done by PhoneGap and every once in a while tiny traffic from the plugin location post. I put the app in the background and continued watching it, after one hour suddenly ddms showed constant traffic accounted to my app
[image]
This traffic summed up to couple of MB after a few minutes already and seems to be the reason for the crazy data usage system report
[image]

It gets even stranger, the app logs a lot, i.e. PhoneGap logs every javascript execution & html loading etc. and my plugin logs as soon as it receives a new location. But there is no logging on the part of my app whatsoever. The only thing logging constantly is the NetworkController informing about `onDataActivity: direction=X`.

```
10-01 13:04:11.273: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=0
10-01 13:04:11.283: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:12.294: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=3
10-01 13:04:12.314: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:13.325: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=0
10-01 13:04:13.335: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:14.206: E/SMD(290): DCD ON
10-01 13:04:14.336: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=3
10-01 13:04:14.336: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:14.877: E/Watchdog(769): !@Sync 1881
10-01 13:04:16.358: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=0
10-01 13:04:16.358: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:17.049: I/Monitor(769): SIOP:: Current AP = 350, CP = 0
10-01 13:04:17.209: E/SMD(290): DCD ON
10-01 13:04:17.369: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=3
10-01 13:04:17.379: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:18.390: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=2
10-01 13:04:18.400: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:19.441: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=3
10-01 13:04:19.441: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:20.212: E/SMD(290): DCD ON
10-01 13:04:23.215: E/SMD(290): DCD ON
10-01 13:04:23.486: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=0
10-01 13:04:23.486: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:24.487: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=3
10-01 13:04:24.487: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:26.209: E/SMD(290): DCD ON
10-01 13:04:26.499: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=0
10-01 13:04:26.509: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:27.050: I/Monitor(769): SIOP:: Current AP = 350, CP = 0
10-01 13:04:27.520: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=3
10-01 13:04:27.520: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:28.531: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=0
10-01 13:04:28.541: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
10-01 13:04:29.192: D/BatteryService(769): update start
10-01 13:04:29.202: D/BatteryService(769): level:89, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4242, temperature: 379, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303394, invalid charger:0, online:4, charge type:1, current avg:0
10-01 13:04:29.202: D/BatteryService(769): Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
10-01 13:04:29.202: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(1232): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
10-01 13:04:29.202: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(1232): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
10-01 13:04:29.202: D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(1232):  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true
10-01 13:04:29.212: E/SMD(290): DCD ON
10-01 13:04:29.542: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): onDataActivity: direction=3
10-01 13:04:29.552: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1232): refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
```

Can anybody explain this? I have been trying to reproduce this behaviour, but it does not reoccur, but still it bugs me.